# Connect jdbc via oracle wallet

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-wallet

Based on [oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCA/oraclewallet.htm), I create a wallet

```
mkstore -wrl /tmp/wl -create
```

Add a credential

```
mkstore -wrl /tmp/wl -createCredential localhost:1521/myservice user pass
```

In my java application, I want to connect to the database via this wallet

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception { 
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
  System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "/tmp/wl");
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("WHAT TO PUT HERE?");
}
```

But I don't know how to fill the connection string.
I would like NOT to use tnsnames.ora
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, use of tnsnames.ora was required when using a wallet for authentication, even for JDBC Thin connections. The connection alias in tnsnames.ora is matched to the connection alias in the wallet to provide the correct credential for a given connection.

That said, the *latest* documentation seems to say that you can enter a connection string along the lines of `myhost:1521/myservice` or `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost-scan)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)))` as the db_connect_string parameter in the wallet. This would presumably negate the need for tnsnames.ora, as long as your connection URL after the "@" matched the db_connect_string in the wallet.

You connection URL then looks something like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myservice
```

Comment: Thank you @pmdba,  i have a question, if tnsnames.ora is required, why they allow us to set the connection string into the wallet? Wwhat is the use of the connection string?

Comment: Like this: mkstore -wrl /tmp/wl -createCredential localhost:1521/myservice user pass

Comment: Good point: i'm revising my answer

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i can make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can pass wallet related connection properties as part of the connection URL. You can skip using tnsnames.ora.
See [JDBC developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-843F6EC2-EDFD-4A88-98DE-B45E1CEADC0E) for some examples.